# Symfony 4 run slowly on windows 10

Tags: php, symfony

I installed symfony 4 on windows machine. I created a controller and returned json data. I sended request in postman and response time is 1-5 second. It's very slowly this response time.

```
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
/**
* Class ScrapingController
* @package App\Controller
* @Route("/scraping")
*/
class ScrapingController extends AbstractController
{
   /**
   * @Route("/", name="scraping", methods={"GET"})
   */
   public function index(){
     return $this->json(['test'=>'ok']);
   }
}
```

I run the project with this command.

`php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public/`

would you help me with this topic?

Comment: Is it slow the second time you make the call from postman?

Comment: Did you seed the Symfony cache.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, it is slow the every time.

Comment: Do you have XDebug enabled in PHP? If yes - did you tried to disable it? Do you run your application in `dev` or `prod` environment? If it is in `dev` - is situation changes if you will switch to `prod`?

Comment: Do you use docker?

Comment: @marv255 no, I didn't use

Comment: @Flying XDebug disabled in php. Is there a different method?

Comment: Do you have enough memory to run Apache/MySQL(with the config you have)  and the client browser

Comment: Maybe it will be good idea to enable XDebug, enable profiler for it, collect profiler dump and analyze it. For example it can be some kind of blocking access e.g. from filesystem or database. Btw, is your disk, site is located on, is local and not encrypted? Do you have some kind of antivirus that may run in aggressive mode? Did you tried to eliminate browser by calling your site through `curl`?

Comment: If you're running on windows, do you actually use windows' powershell/command line, or do you use the linux subsystem / bash?